# Substring Method in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have this field:'Pb PS Drop , HSPA Drop sur KAI4053F02' .
i would like to take from this field only the part from the beginner to 'sur'and read the part before and after',' each for himself
i tried this query :

```
 SUBSTR(tofind,1,'sur');
```

but it's not working.thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need [SUBSTRING_INDEX()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/2042

```
SELECT 
  SUBSTRING_INDEX('Pb PS Drop , HSPA Drop sur KAI4053F02','sur',1) `Before`,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX('Pb PS Drop , HSPA Drop sur KAI4053F02','sur',-1) `After`
```